SQL Server does not allow cycles with on delete on foreign keys, causing problems with the database first and code first Entity Framework approaches
Suppose we have a user who creates a team with members in it, in which he is the leader.
enter image description here
The relation is supposed to look like this, but it is tricky to come up with a solution, which would not to face an error such as:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint XXX on table XXX may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

Sure I can come around it by just not specifying the action on delete, but that does not feel right + it would cause problems when trying the first code approach with Entity Framework, as it assumes a lot of different things (including on delete statements)  which result in errors during the update state. What would be the best approach in those kind of situations?
The SQL:
CREATE TABLE team (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE team ADD CONSTRAINT pk_team PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INTEGER,
    user_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (user_id);
ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT uc_user_email UNIQUE (email);

CREATE TABLE team_user (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE team_user ADD CONSTRAINT pk_team_user PRIMARY KEY (id, user_id);

ALTER TABLE user ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_team FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES team (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE team_user ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_user_team FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES team (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE team_user ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_user_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

And the entity framework models code:
User:
public class MyUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> PartTeams { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> OwnTeams { get; set; }

}

public class MyUserConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyUser> builder) { 
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasMany(x=>x.PartTeams)
            .WithMany(x=>x.Members);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.OwnTeams)
            .WithOne(x => x.Leader)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LeaderId);
    }
}

-Team:
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LeaderId { get; set; }

    public MyUser Leader { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyUser> Members { get; set; }
}

public TeamConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Team>
{
    public void Configure(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<Team> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);


        builder.HasMany(x => x.Members)
            .WithMany(x => x.PartTeams);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Leader)
            .WithMany(x => x.OwnTeams)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.LeaderId);
    }
}

-Context:
public class WebAppContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyUserConfigurations());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TeamConfigurations());
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=KUISEYE\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False");
    }
    public DbSet<MyUser>? my_users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team>? teams { get; set; }
}

Note: the SQLl code and Entity Framework code are NOT connected, they represent distinct (database and code first) approaches.

I don't follow what you are asking here. If you are getting an error, demonstrate the code you are using to get that error.

here you go, I updated it

Well, you have no option. You have to prevent that SQL exception. Only one relationship can have cascade delete, it's up to you to choose which one suits you best. I don't understand al these problems you seem to anticipate. It only affects deleting records.

An option would be not to use cascading deletes at all. I have seen this multiple times that people adding new cascading delete rules naively and then being surprise by the complete cascading delete chain they build and then have the question of undoing the deletion of almost 100% of their database content. Imho consider being explicit with deleting as best practice.

Honestly, I don't think I've ever used the CASCADE feature apart from for demonstration purposes. When developing, I always end up going down the explicit route. Some of those tasks will be triggers, but often I control the deletes in a stored procedure and the application or automation calls that instead. If someone then needs to DELETE from the table manually, they either need to also write their explicit statements or, more likely, they'll call the procedure as well.

I recommend not using cascade delete, but writing instead off triggers or stored procedures for deleting. That way you and only you have clear control of the deletes
